# How to make f(g(x)) give None value with particularly function?

Tags: python

I have a problem that I input `f_5` and `f_6` to the req1 and I receive error here.

The function `f(x) / g(x)` in `###2` is fine with `f(x) = 1/x` and `g(x) = 0` and gives me None value.

But the function `f(g(x))` in `###1` gives an error with "division by zero" problem. So how to make it give me None value ?

The functions `###2` and `###1` work well with "not particularly" math function.

```
from sympy import *
import numpy as np

global x, y, z, t
x, y, z, t = symbols("x, y, z, t")

def req1(f, g, a):
    arr = []
    ###1
    z = f(g(x))
    print(z)
    i = diff(z, x).subs(x, a)
    if not i.is_real:
        i = None
    arr.append(i)
    ###2
    z = f(x) / g(x)
    print(z)
    i = diff(z, x).subs(x, a)
    if not i.is_real:
        i = None
    arr.append(i)
    print(tuple(arr))
    return None

def f_5(x):
    return  1 / x
def f_6(x):
    return 0
req1(f_5, f_6, 0)
```

Comment: You could use `try/except` to catch the error and return None.

Comment: You can either test x for equality to zero and return None or use a try/except and handle the ZeroDivisionError exception. Having said that, you don't want f_5 to return None because you use it in what would be an inappropriate manner